# Raspberry Pi + preamp problems

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi2

I have written a python script that takes audio in through a SYBA external USB Stereo Sound Adapter. It works great when I plug my cell phone playing audio into it, but now I am trying to use the line out from an Audio Buddy preamp and the audio is not registering. I am using ALSA Audio with the following read settings:

```
    data_in = aa.PCM(aa.PCM_CAPTURE, aa.PCM_NONBLOCK, 'hw:1')
    data_in.setchannels(1) # I am splitting the stereo signal
    data_in.setrate(8000)
    data_in.setformat(aa.PCM_FORMAT_S8)

    data_in.setperiodsize(256)
```

Does anyone have any insight into why this might not be working?

Comment: Presumably you've tried plugging the output of the Audio Buddy into a normal amp and listening to it, to make sure it's actually working? (Can you see the green SIG light lighting up on the Audio Buddy?)

Comment: Another thing that occurs -- how's your wiring set up? If you're only recording one channel from the stereo, say the left channel, but you've wired just one output from the Audio Buddy to the right channel of the SYBA, then you won't get any audio registering. (It'll work with the phone because the phone will play two-channel stereo, so it'll record one of them no matter what.)

Comment: Here is the problem: line in is different than mic in. See: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/27539/difference-between-microphone-and-line-in-inputs

Comment: Huh? You haven't mentioned using a mic at all. (If you've got a mic plugged into the Audio Buddy, it should be converting that to a line-level output to go into the same line input on the sound card as you plugged your phone into. Converting from low-impedance XLR inputs to a line-level signal is exactly what a pre-amp like the Audio Buddy is for.)

Comment: I was using the term mic in to differentiate between line in and microphone in inputs.